# undefined is not an object(evaluating ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker)

Tags: react-native

```
var ImagePicker = require('react-native-image-picker');
call() {   
    var options = {
      title: 'Select Avatar',
      customButtons: [
        {name: 'fb', title: 'Choose Photo from Facebook'},
      ],
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images'
      }
    };
      ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      }
      else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      }
      else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      }
      else {
        let source = { uri: response.uri };

        // You can also display the image using data:
        // let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

        this.setState({
          avatarSource: source
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I call this function from render onClick. I am using

> react-native-image-picker@0.26.7

But it is giving me undefined is not an object error. Also please tell me how can I link it to phone gallery to choose the image. Please suggest me solution
[image]

Comment: did you run react-native run-android after you added the code of the native android ?

Comment: I didn't. But now when I ran **react-native run-android** it is working. Thank you. Can you please also tell how to link it to phone gallery

Comment: It is working on android but on IOS there is following error - **Can not read property 'showImagePicker' of undefined**

Comment: you need to run react-native run-ios for IOS...

Comment: Sorry I can't tell how to link it(I don't know it), I never used the library before.. but I know this error from another libs

Comment: mmm I am an android developer, I never used ios development before... hope a good luck

Answer (score 6):

If you update your import:

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
         // code here
};
```

things are gonna work

Answer (score 2):

First you must link the module.

```
react-native link react-native-image-picker
```

Then check below files:

android/app/build.gradle：`compile project(':react-native-image-picker')`

android/setting.gradle：

```
include ':react-native-image-picker'
project(':react-native-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android')
```

android/app/src/..../MainApplication
[image]

The issue is here:

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/414#issuecomment-265060406

Comment: Thank you @DennisFrea. This issue resolved when I ran  **react-native run-android** command

Comment: Fyi..... only manual link if you are using < RN 0.60 otherwise if RN > 0.60 it should already include Autolinking.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is cool way to solve this problem:

```
import * as ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker"

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.CameraIconContent}
          onPress={() =>
            ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(
              {
                mediaType: 'photo',
                includeBase64: false,
                maxHeight: 200,
                maxWidth: 200,
              },
              (response) => {
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({resourcePath: response});
              },
            )
          }
                    >
                    <Image
                        source={CAMERA_ICON}
                            resizeMode = "contain"
                            style={{
                                width: 20,
                                height: 20
                            }}
                    />
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using version 4.x.x, follow these steps:

**First**: go to AndroidManifest in 'android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' and add the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

**After**: Access the camera as in this example:

```
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker"

async function cameraPermission() {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA);
    if(granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      // if get here, the user has accepted the permissions
    } else {
      // if get here, the user did NOT accepted the permissions
    }
}

function takePhoto() {
    cameraPermission();

    ImagePicker.launchCamera({
        mediaType: 'photo',
        maxHeight: 600,
        maxWidth: 800
    }, res => {
        if (!res.didCancel) {
            this.setState({ imageUri: res.uri });
        }
    });
}
```

Attention! if you are going to use ios you also need to grant permissions

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded my old project, I had the same problem. The `react-native-image-picker` version was `^0.26.7` that is very old version actually.

The previous code was

```
let ImagePicker = require('react-native-image-picker');
     
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
           console.log('Response = ', response);
                if (response.didCancel) {
                    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
                }
                else if (response.error) {
                    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
                }
                else if (response.customButton) {
                    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
                }
                else {
                    this.profileImageObject = response;
                    let source = { uri: response.uri };
      ;              this.setState({
                        profilePicture: source,
                        isProfilePicture: true
                    })
                }
            });
```

The error was as like the following screenshot

---

[image: imagepicker error]

---

I just import `all` from the `library` and use `launchImageLibrary` function as follows:

```
import * as ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker"

ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {...}
```

Now it works for me. I hope it will help developers as well.

Answer (score -1):

1. Install module linking it to react native:
   `npm install react-native-image-picker --save`
2. Restart your react native server
3. Run your app again to load the new installed module:
   `npx react-native run-android`