# React Native Image Picker: null is not an object (evaluating 'ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker')

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-image-picker

I installed react-native-image-picker according to the documentation.
When I am trying to select the image from the phone (after hitting the button), the emulator is giving me this error-
`null is not an object (evaluating 'ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker')`

My React native's version is 0.59.8

and image picker's version is 0.28.0

this the code-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker";

export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    pickedImage: null
  }

  reset = () => {
    this.setState({
      pickedImage: null
    });
  }




pickImageHandler = () => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker({title: "Pick an Image", maxWidth: 800, maxHeight: 600}, res => {
      if (res.didCancel) {
        console.log("User cancelled!");
      } else if (res.error) {
        console.log("Error", res.error);
      } else {
        this.setState({
          pickedImage: { uri: res.uri }
        });

      }
    });
  }



       resetHandler = () =>{
            this.reset();
          }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Pick Image From Camera and Gallery </Text>
        <View style={styles.placeholder}>
          <Image source={this.state.pickedImage} style={styles.previewImage} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.button}>

          <Button title="Pick Image" onPress={this.pickImageHandler} />

          <Button title="Reset" onPress={this.resetHandler} />

         </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think open your android studio, you didn't provided permission in manifest

Comment: no, I give it. By writing `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` these line in manifest file

Comment: please try once this -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-imagepicker

Comment: @ Mayur Coceptioni this one is `react-native-imagepicker`. Is there any difference in   `react-native-imagepicker` and `react-native-image-picker` ?

Comment: I think leave everything and try this -> https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker   , I tried this many times and it is working very fluently bor both android and IOS.

Comment: Maaan!!, i finally decided to use `rn-fetch-blob`

Comment: Follow This:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68378454/7921804

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downgraded image picker's version to `28.0.0` and then rebuilt the app. Now it is working.

Comment: I am using the React-native-image-picker v3.1.1.
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.ImagePickerManager.launchImageLibrary')

Comment: same here. did you get the solution?

Comment: Follow This:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68378454/7921804

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug with the current version. I've experienced this, what I did was to uninstall the current version on the image-picker package, and installed the version `@1.1.0`:

Or you can simply downgrade your current version.

> 1. `npm uninstall react-native-image-picker`
> 2. `npm install react-native-image-picker@1.1.0 --save`
> 3. `react-native link react-native-image-picker`
> 4. `cd ios`
> 5. `pod install`
> 6. cd ..

Stop and re-run your Packager or Bundler

Then reset your cache

> npm start --reset-cache

Comment: Follow This:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68378454/7921804

Answer (score 0):

Not `ImagePickerManager`You can use `ImagePicker`

**Example**

```js
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

// More info on all the options is below in the API Reference... just some common use cases shown here
const options = {
  title: 'Select Avatar',
  customButtons: [{ name: 'fb', title: 'Choose Photo from Facebook' }],
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'images',
  },
};

/**
 * The first arg is the options object for customization (it can also be null or omitted for default options),
 * The second arg is the callback which sends object: response (more info in the API Reference)
 */
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  console.log('Response = ', response);

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
  } else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  } else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
  } else {
    const source = { uri: response.uri };

    // You can also display the image using data:
    // const source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

    this.setState({
      avatarSource: source,
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I have updated my question...you may take a look at it

Comment: @AfifaKhan Where is import??

Comment: @AfifaKhan Did you link?? `react-native link react-native-image-picker`

Comment: @AfifaKhan install  before link `yarn add react-native-image-picker`

Comment: yes I did it, but displaying the same error after hitting the select button

Comment: Follow This:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68378454/7921804

Answer (score 0):

Build the project in android studio and if you are encountering an error like:

this.options.saveToPhotos && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.P && ....

in your **projectName/android/build.gradle** update these

```
   ext {
     buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
     minSdkVersion = 21
     compileSdkVersion = 29
     targetSdkVersion = 29
}
```

and also update this

```
  afterEvaluate {
        project -> if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 29
                buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
            }
        }
    }
```