# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeImagePicker.default.showImagePicker')

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

Using React Image Picker i am facing this error:
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeImagePicker.default.showImagePicker')

This is what happens when i click on image picker function

Mobile Screenshot:

[image: Error Image]

This is my Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text,Button } from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

const options = {
    title: 'Select Avatar',
    customButtons: [{ name: 'fb', title: 'Choose Photo from Facebook' }],
    storageOptions: {
      skipBackup: true,
      path: 'images',
    },
  };

function Picker(){
    const openPicker =()=>{
      ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
        console.log('Response = ', response);
      
        if (response.didCancel) {
          console.log('User cancelled image picker');
        } else if (response.error) {
          console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        } else if (response.customButton) {
          console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        } else {
          const source = { uri: response.uri };
      
          // You can also display the image using data:
          // const source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };
      
          console.log(source)
        }
      });
    }
    return(
        <View>
            <Button onPress={openPicker} title="Open image picker"></Button>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Picker;
```

Comment: what is the exact version of `react-native-image-picker` that you are using? You can check it under the `package.json` file.

Comment: If you are using `react-native-image-picker 3.x.x` version, `showImagePicker ` will no longer work. please refer [here for the migration guide](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker#migration-from-2xx-to-3xx) . You need to use `launchImageLibrary` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker#launchimagelibrary)

Comment: I am using image picker version 3.1.2 . I was actually following a tutorial in which they downloaded the new version and then they used the old docs which worked for them. The version just launchImageLibrary(options?, callback)? nothing else as before the 2.x.x version needed the whole code.

Comment: I don't know how it worked on the tutorial. but as per the [docs](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker#launchimagelibrary). You need to change your [import statement](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker#methods) and use [launchimagelibrary](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker#launchimagelibrary) with [options](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker#options) and [response](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker#options)

Comment: I changed it with launch image library but now i am getting this error. TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...(0, _reactNativeImagePicker.default)...').  Can you change my updated required code.

Comment: Same issue here, has anyone gotten this work?

Comment: Follow This:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68378454/7921804

Answer (score 30):

I had this same issue and this is how I solved it.

`import * as ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker"`

Comment: Follow This:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68378454/7921804

Comment: Yes this worked for me

Answer (score 8):

If your **react-native-image-picker** version is **3.x.x** then, replace the above code with these lines,

```
import {launchCamera, launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker'; // Migration from 2.x.x to 3.x.x => showImagePicker API is removed.
...

const openPicker =()=>{
  launchCamera(options, (response) => { // Use launchImageLibrary to open image gallery
    console.log('Response = ', response);
  
    if (response.didCancel) {
      console.log('User cancelled image picker');
    } else if (response.error) {
      console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
    } else if (response.customButton) {
      console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
    } else {
      const source = { uri: response.uri };
  
      // You can also display the image using data:
      // const source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };
  
      console.log(source)
    }
  });
```

Read the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker)

Comment: Please give better explanation as to why the above code works.

Comment: It works because we all found and copied code containing `showImagePicker`, but that method doesn't exist in version 3.x.x. So, we should use `launchImageLibrary ` or `launchCamera`.

Comment: @FilipSavic in my case image gallery is opening up and closes at the same moment in ios. however android works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: @R.singh No idea... sorry :/
Maybe check if someone has already filed an issue on their GitHub.

Comment: Follow This:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68378454/7921804

Answer (score 8):

**Issue:**
`import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker"`

**Solution:**  
`import * as ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker"`

Answer (score 4):

check your lib version if its 3x then try something like this

```
import * as ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker"


                <Button onPress={() =>
                        ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(
                          {
                            mediaType: 'photo',
                            includeBase64: false,
                            maxHeight: 200,
                            maxWidth: 200,
                          },
                          (response) => {
                            console.log(response);
                            this.setState({resourcePath: response});
                          },
                        )
                      }
                title="Select Image"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
  import { ImagePicker } from 'react-native-image-picker',
```

with

```
var ImagePicker = require('react-native-image-picker');
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

**showImagePicker API is removed.**

use Direct launchCamera or launchImageLibrary

import {launchCamera, launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';

Answer (score 0):

you can downgrade your version of the image picker library I am facing same issue then I am using this CLI command to downgrade a version of the image picker
npm install react-native-image-picker@2.3.4
same like you can use this command