# Cannot read property 'launchImageLibrary' of undefined react-native-image-picker

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-image-picker

My feature offers a small image icon as a touchable to upload or take a picture, using `"react-native-image-picker": "^3.3.2"`.

I'm getting error: `Cannot read property 'launchImageLibrary' of undefined`, same as this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1477) but as you can see, my code already have the import as they told to.

Here's my full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Alert
} from 'react-native';
import { launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';

const ImageUpload: React.FC<any> = ({}) => {

    function showMessage() {
        Alert.alert("Upload image", "Choose a option", [
            {
                text: 'Camera',
                onPress: () => openCamera(),
            },
            {
                text: 'Gallery',
                onPress: () => openLibrary()
            },
        ]);
    }

    const openLibrary = () => {

        const options = {
            storageOptions: {
              skipBackup: true,
              path: 'images',
            },
          };
        launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
            console.log(response);
        });

    }

    const openCamera = () => {
        //ongoing
    }

    return(
        <>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>showMessage()}>
                <Image source={require('./picture.png')} style={{ width: 70, height: 70 }}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </>
     );
};

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    ImageIcon: {
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
    }

});

export default ImageUpload;
```

Also, In VS Code, I have this error when calling `launchImageLibrary`:
[image]

I have already perfomed a `npx pod-install`.

Comment: Same issue! Haven't found any solution yet myself despite hours of trying

Answer (score 6):

Importing it like this solved my issue;

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case with Android, restarting the emulator fixed the problem.
`npm run android`

Answer (score 2):

It took me a very long time to get this to work but this worked for me.

```js
< Button onPress = {
  () =>
  ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary({
      mediaType: 'photo',
      includeBase64: false,
      maxHeight: 200,
      maxWidth: 200,
    },
    (response) => {
      console.log(response);
      this.setState({
        resourcePath: response
      });
    },
  )
}
title = "Select Image" / >
```

References:

- [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeImagePicker.default.showImagePicker')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65553830/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-reactnativeimagepicker-defau)

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me, I think there is some bug with expo and native libraries.

To test I did the following:

1. npm expo prebuild (will create the native codes in the ios and android folder)
2. npm react-native start

It worked for me.

Note: this error only happened on the iOS emulator, on Android the error did not occur

Answer (score 0):

i use "react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.5",

i just restart metro "npx react-native start" or "npx react-native start --reset-cache"

and rerun metro bundler "npx react-native run-android"

my code is

```
import { launchImageLibrary } from "react-native-image-picker";

 handleChangePhoto = () => {
    launchImageLibrary({ noData: true }, (response) => {
      console.log(response);
      // if (response) {
      //   setPhoto(response);
      // }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with Expo and encountering issues with image picking with this library, it might be more effective to utilize the expo-image-picker library instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Answer (score -4):

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
```